# Linear equation involving square

Tags: linear-algebra

Please assist with solving linear equation
$$(2x-5)(2x+5)=(2x-3)^2$$

I tried to square root but it doesn't make sense.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Simply expand and set =0, the result is a linear equation.

Comment: How do you know that it is linear ???

Comment: @DonAntonio: of course it is. This question is to the OP who mysteriously knows that the equation is linear though is unable to solve.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I see...Since your comment came *after* the one by Squirtle I thought you meant to ask him.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I would have addressed him explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot decide if an equation is linear or not if the equation is not written in the canonical form, i.e. if it is not written as:

polynomial in the unknown $x=0$ .

In your case , reducing to the canonical form, you find:
$$
4x^2-25=4x^2+9-12x \quad \iff \quad 12x-34=0
$$
so the equation has degree $1$ in $x$.

Comment: You are welcome.  Don't forget to accept if you want.